# Does there exist a communication based vector drawing platform?

Tags: model-view-controller, networking, graphics, language-agnostic, vector-graphics

I have an idea for a programmatic vector drawing platform, but I would rather not implement it myself if it exists. The platform should be language agnostic, and approximate the following description of some of its properties:

1. a server that manages the states of a set of vector displays, and communicates with:
2. a class of clients connecting to send drawing instructions to these displays
3. a class that connects to view the state of some drawing context and send keyboard/mouse events
4. a class that is listening for events, and possibly communicating back with the class of clients described by #2 independent from the graphics server.
5. Ideally #1 is cross platform, and the client side of #3 would have a browser based viewer

Does something like this exist already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on a vector graphics library for a while.

http://www.vectoroid.com

It loads SVG and can serialise individual objects / groups to JSON. so you would just have to send them over the pipe.

It an early stage project, but I am trying to raise awareness, there is a discussion list here.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vectoroid-discuss

it's a bit bare at the moment :(